# Mac proxy settings don't work but do work in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, proxy

I have a proxy running on my phone and I am trying to connect to that proxy. When I set the proxy settings in Firefox directly (Settings > Network Settings > Manual Proxy Configuration) it works fine, but when I use the exact same settings in Mac it does not work.

Firefox works fine in manual mode, but doesn't when using "Use system proxy".

Firefox manual proxy settings:
[image: Firefox]

Mac proxy settings:
[image]

Here is also from Terminal using curl with and without manually specifying the proxy:

```
$ curl -I example.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com

$ curl -Ix michaels-iphone.local:8888 example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: Sorry, but are you actually using your phone as a proxy server?

Comment: @unbeatable101 Yes, as an alternative when I don't have Personal Hotspot available on my phone due to my carrier.

Comment: interesting, how are you accomplishing that?

Comment: @unbeatable101 iProxy is project I'm using from GitHub. But you can write an app that acts as a web server or proxy. Apple probably won't allow it on the store, depending on the purpose, but you can still deploy whatever you want to your phone.

Comment: Same here, command line is not working but I can reach from browser

Comment: Are you by any chance using a VPN? I know that Cisco AnyConnect screws with the routing tables on the machine its running on making this impossible through system settings

Comment: @Asad-ullahKhan No, just default macOS settings no vpn or proxies apps.